# not catch DbUpdateConcurrencyException?

Tags: entity-framework

i  set a break point  at `var c = context.SaveChanges()` , then update sql `update [Student] set Name ='456' where PriKey =1`  in Sqlserver Management Studio,  continue, somstimes  the program can not catch  `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`, why happen this situation?

```cs
 public class OfficeContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                @"Data Source=192.168.31.215;User ID=hj;Password=hj123;Database=office;Integrated Security=false");
            optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
        }


        [Table("Student")]
        public class Student
        {

            [Column("PriKey")]
            [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int Id { get; set; }

            [Timestamp]
            [Column("VerCol")]
            public virtual byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

            [Column("Name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }

   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var context = new OfficeContext()){
                try
                {
                    var a = context.Students.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
                    a.Name = "123";
                    var c = context.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
         
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably because the name wasn't actually changed. It was "123" when you fetched the record.

Comment: yes,   add `context.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Modified;`  can fix the problem, or assign `a.Name`  differently also can fix the problem

Comment: So, problem solved I guess.

Comment: yes，thank you, friend！